# When $P$ is a truth set of statement $p$ and $P= \emptyset $, is $p \rightarrow\ q$ true for any statement $q$?

Tags: logic

"if $p$, then $q$" is always true when $P \subset\ Q$, and so I can assume my assumption is true.

But the problem is, I am not sure that "if $p$" would even make sense when $P= \emptyset\ $.

So, is "$p \rightarrow\ q$" for any statement $q$ in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P=\varnothing$ then a statement like $$x\in P\implies x\in Q$$ is always true. We speak of "vacuously true" in that situation.

To get hold on it suppose that it is *not* true. Then we must have an $x$ satisfying: $$x\in P\text{ and }x\notin Q$$

But such $x$ does not exist, since there is no $x$ that satisfies $x\in\varnothing=P$.

I hope this answers your question.